# Is it easy to happen latch up for low speed MCU?

Tags: microcontroller

I have experience of latch up phenomenon when I use 8bit max. 16Mhz AVR and PIC in the noisy environments.
Is it easy to happen latch up for low speed MCU?
Because, high speed(180Mhz, 32bit) MCU has very fast rising, falling time when changing logic (0, 1).
Is there any technical document?

Comment: Latch up depends on how you use the MCU, maybe you use it incorrectly. And how susceptible the MCU is for latch-up does not depend on the speed. Maybe you are not experiencing latch-up, but something else? How do you use the AVR? Or PIC? Schematics are important, also PCB design.

Comment: Post an annotated schematic and a focused picture of the application environment. Also note anything that happens when it latches up. Be sure to show the power supply and all of the connections especially ground.

Comment: Thanks for your reply